# How can I prevent users from updating the status to anything but closed?

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to prevent a customer from updating the status of a case to anything other than closed with a validation rule.  What I have works when I update the status, but also for closed.  Here is what I have...

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(Status),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed)")),
$User.ProfileId == "00e0x000000MYby")
```

Comment: I figured it out.  Added a ) by accident.  Silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND(
ISCHANGED(Status),
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed")),
$User.ProfileId == "00e0x000000MYby")
```

Comment: Looks like this answer might've been auto-flagged because of length. I know you went over this in a comment on your question, but I think that explaining what the issue was in your answer proper would be a good idea. If you'd like to expand your answer even more, you could go over how putting things on separate lines (which you have done here) and indenting can make spotting stray parenthesis easier.